# Unable to create a shortcut for calling a number on Android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

This is an example of a code for creating a direct shortcut that calls a specific number and which works on Android M and below.

```
public void installShortcutGetId(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"MyCallShortcut");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:77777777")));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon));
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The same code doesn't work anymore on Android N, I can see in the logcat the following:

```
 /com.android.launcher3 E/InstallShortcutReceiver: Ignoring malicious intent tel:77777777#Intent;action=android.intent.action.CALL;end
```

If I change ACTION_CALL to ACTION_DIAL, it works on Android N but that's not what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to make a direct call through the shortcut.

In terms of permissions, I have these 2 included and CALL_PHONE requested at run-time.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: did you request the permission before running `installShortcutGetId()`

Comment: yes definitely. @petey

Answer (score 1):

Just because your app has the CALL_PHONE permission doesn't mean the launcher has that permission: that's why your shortcut cannot be created.

You could instead create a shortcut to an empty activity of your own and start the `ACTION_CALL` Intent from that activity.